# Typescript recognize arrow function as function

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

is there any way to make the editor recognize arrow functions as function instead of symbol/property?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: you are missing the leading `=` after async. `async = (...) => {`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to write it as a regular function / method, without the `=>` part.

Comment: Hello, how can this kind of answer help me? If I take the => out of it it becomes a regular function, not an arrow function. Try using your super powers to really help people ;)